# WSO2 MDM Setup Guide

Tags: wso2, mdm

I read your documentation and did all the installations and all, but when I started getting confused is the Server setup aspect of it. I'm a mobile developer(Android, iOS). And my current work needs EMDM and I saw your work which is Very great. My problem is, I don't know how to go about setting up the server and ip and ports for it work. I did all the Script works, and running with java YAJSW. But, setting the iP and trying to access with mobile, sorry I'm confused at that point. Please, I'm a newbie or no body when it comes to server interpretation, I'm all just coding and that. Please, should you have a more detail help, I wouldn't mind. Thank You.

Comment: Can you tell me which step in the documentation you are stuck and also whether you are testing in your local machine or in a server?

Comment: I want to configure for server, but I don't know how I can go about that. And also, I don't know how to go about local itself. But, it'll be good if I can create a server for it and use that. Thanks

Comment: And if you can walk me through using AMI, I have an Ubuntu Instance I created yesterday. But, I don't know how to link it.

Comment: You can setup the EMM server in your local machine and test android without any configuration. By default the pack contains the android agent apk. Since you are running the server in your local machine, you need to connect both the Android device and your machine to a wifi connect, so that both can ping each other.

Comment: After that you can follow the go through the user guide (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/User+Guide) in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have problems configuring WSO2 EMM for iOS devices. We are conducting a complementary webinar on "Getting your iOS Device Managed by WSO2 Enterprise Mobility Manager on Tuesday, September 23, 2014 at 10 AM PDT. This webinar will cover:

- Overview of WSO2 EMM
- How to create the iOS EMM agent
- Configuring the WSO2 EMM server for iOS
- How to enroll an iOS device to WSO2 EMM
- iOS device management with WSO2 EMM
- Create and monitor policies for iOS devices
- Create your own Enterprise Mobile App Store

For more information and registration , http://wso2.com/library/webinars/2014/09/getting-your-ios-device-managed-by-wso2-enterprise-mobility-manager/